# Поберегите порох на случай прихода либералов

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста,

*Поберегите порох на случай прихода либералов.*

это одно единое главное предложение или мы имеем дело с условным (*на случай = если*)?

Я правильно думаю: если нет запятой, нет придаточного?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

> *Поберегите порох на случай прихода...*

Это одно предложение. Союзов в нём нет, придаточных тоже нет; ***на случай***  — [**предлог:**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/188910)

> **на слу́чай**
>
> ```
> предл. с род.
>
> Употребляется при указании на допущение возможности какого-либо действия.
> ```
>
> Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.

Для постановки запятой в данном предложении оснований нет, можно перед ***на случай***  поставить интонационное тире.

Answer (score 0):

Сравните два варианта:

1) Простое предложение, распространенное обстоятельство цели (зачем? для чего?): Поберегите порох на случай прихода либералов.

2)  Сложноподчиненное предложение промежуточного характера.

Поберегите порох на **тот** случай, **если**  придут либералы (определительное придаточное с добавочным обстоятельственным значением условия/времени).

Поберегите порох,  **на  случай если**  придут либералы (придаточное цели).

В СПП обязательно должны быть **подчинительные союзы или союзные слова**.